# Installing php5-fpm but missing www.conf on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php-fpm, php5

I am installing php5-fpm on my ubuntu system but could not able to find **www.conf** file under pool.d directory.

In my /etc/php5/fpm folder, there are only 2 directories - **conf.d** and **pool.d**

Command which I am using -

```
apt-get install php5-fpm
```

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is correct.  Use `dpkg -L` to see what files the package installed.

```
$ dpkg -L php5-fpm
```

If you still can't find the file, backup any files you've edited, uninstall/reinstall the package then check again.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge php5-fpm; sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
```

Comment: Yes - purging works! I just tried to re-install php5-fpm - but did not tried purge command